# Trying to find a young adult fiction book with a boy and girl that met up in a post nuclear landscape

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I am trying to find the name of a book I read as a young teenager set in a post nuclear apocalypse world with a young teenage boy and girl met up. I think it is a book series and maybe I read the first or second book in the series.

At one point in the story they are both bathing in a cave with a lake and trying not to peek at each other.

I read it in the mid nineties and I think it was from the mid 1980's, it wasn't very old but I did get it from a local library so goodness knows!

I have tried looking for this book on and off for years and can never pin it down. All suggestions welcome.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_for_Zachariah?

Comment: It might be helpful to know when you were a young teenager and wether the book was newly published by that time, so as to try and help dating it better.

Comment: Apologises - I read it in the mid nineties and I think it was from the mid 1980's, it wasn't very old. It wasn't Z for Zachariah and I think it was part of a series of books

Comment: Any chance there was a talking bird in the story?  I have a long-shot hunch but won't make in an answer yet.

Comment: Hi Emsley. I really can't remember a bird but that doesn't mean that there wasn't one. It kind had a 'coming of age' theme to the story

Comment: A little tip: you can notify users by writing an "@" in front of their name. The OP of a post is always notified and you can notify one additional user per comment by writing for example @EmsleyWyatt, so that he sees your response ;) It even autocompletes the name for you.

Comment: Can you remember any more details on this book/series?  There are a few lists around https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/26883.Post_Apocalyptic_Teen_Fiction or https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/44146.YA_Science_Fiction_Dystopian_and_Post_Apocalyptic_Published_in_the_1980s, maybe the one you're looking for is one of these?